# HTML - Required Textbox and Submit Button

Tags: html, button, textbox, onclick

```
<label for="first_name">First Name</label> 
<input name="FirstName" type="text" id="first_name" required/> 
<input type="submit"/>
```

The above code shows a textbox and a submit button. The textbox can't be left blank or else there will be a message saying "Please fill in this field" once the submit button is clicked on. 
My question is how do I incorporate the `onclick` attribute with the submit button? 
So, if the textbox is not blank, and the submit button is pressed, I want it to execute a function perhaps something like -->`onclick="postNameToDatabase()"` (while still maintaining the blank field message feature).

EDITED: I've tried this: `<input type="submit" onclick="postNameToDatabase()"/>` but the function still executes even though the textbox is blank on a button click.

Comment: Can you reword your question and perhaps use some formatting?

Comment: Okay, I formatted my code and reworded my question :P

Comment: Are you opposed to using php?

Comment: php is fine. As long as it works. :P

Comment: Cool, so to clairify....when the form isn't empty, you would like the first name (form content) to be written to a database?

Comment: I prefer using javascript if possible.

Comment: php solution is safer and "right" way to do it, i've added a solution. any questions feel free to ask away.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this with jQuery:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    if($('input[type=text]').val() == '') {
        return false;
        //Display error message
    } else {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### PHP Answer

You need to use a server side language to connect to a database, this has the benefit of being safer as your credentials aren't shown in the source code for people to steal, and how will you connect if your browser doesn't allow javascript?

You need to add your database name, table, username and password.

### Use this code

```html
   <form action=""method="post">
       <label>First Name</label>
       <input type="text" name="FirstName" />
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    
    
    <?php
    
    //add address of database, username and password
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","Username","password") or die('I cannot connect to the database  because: ' . mysql_error());
                  
                  //-select  the database to use, add database name
                  $mydb = mysql_select_db("yourdatabase") or die(mysql_error());

         //add the table in your db
        $strSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO yourtable (FirstName) VALUES ('%s')", 
          @mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["FirstName"]),
         
         // The SQL statement is executed 
     mysql_query($strSQL) or die (mysql_error());
    
     // Close the database connection
     mysql_close();
     
    
    
    
    ?>
    
    
      </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get the value of the text box and check it for being empty. If it is empty throw an error

throw { name: 'Error', message: 'Fill textbox' };